# Asp.Net identity disable some fields

Tags: asp.net-identity

I've recently updated the asp.net identity and now I can't login because it says that it requires new fields, so I tried to recreated the tables and the table users seems to have some extra fields, which I basically do not need.

These fields are: phonenumber, phonenumberconfirmed, twofactorenabled, etc etc ... how can I disable those fiends and say to asp.net identity to not even look for them? Because if I delete them, then I get errors saying it could not find those fields.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the fields you don't need by ignoring their mapping in the DbContext class. For example if you don't want to use the PhoneNumber and PhoneNumberConfirmed you can ignore them in the ApplicationDbContext as below

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Ignore(x => x.PhoneNumber);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Ignore(x => x.PhoneNumberConfirmed);
    }
```

Note that not mapping these fields would lead to not using APIs that use them consequently missing out those features.

Comment: how to ignore a class instead of just properties? for example i don't need the ApplicationUsers table at all because I want to authenticate users against Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing what you want is you would need to implement your own custom user storage classes, like `IdentityUser`,  `UserStore` etc... You can find more info [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity#userstore).